# Retrieve Service and use it in some arbitrary class in net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

There are plenty of examples how to set controllers to use services etc. But what about plain old class? Lets use some simple configuration service

JSON

```
{
  ....,
  "AppSettings": {
    "SchemaFile": "some file name.xml"
  }  
}
```

POCO

```cs
public class AppSettings
{
    public string SchemaFile { get;set; }
}
```

In startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IConfigurationSection appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
  . . . . 
}
```

This is the point where all examples move directly to the controller. But we are going to have plenty of code outside controller. What I need is to access this service using `provider.GetService(typeof(T))` or `provider.GetRequiredService(typeof(T))`, from, lets say a static class

```cs
internal static MyClass
{
    internal static void DosomeThing()
    {
        // acquire my service
        // use it to retrieve some value
        // continue with my logic

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just as the services can be injected into controllers, so too can they be injected into other classes.

static classes however to not lend themselves well to dependency injection by default.

Instead of using a static class, make a regular class and explicitly depend on the desired service via constructor injection

```
internal class MyClass : IMyService {
    readonly AppSettings settings;

    public MyClass(AppSettings settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    internal void DosomeThing() {
        // retrieve some value from settings
        // continue with my logic
    }
}
```

You can then register your desired POCO and utilities with the service container

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    AppSettings appSettings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
    services.AddSingleton(appSettings);
    services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyClass>();
    //. . . . 
}
```

Inject your service where it is needed and it will have access to the POCO when being resolved for injection.

There really is no need to be passing `IServiceProvider` around as that can be seen as a code smell.

Simplifying your design to follow explicit dependency principle should make your code more SOLID and easier to follow and maintain.

Comment: I will be using this to try. But we're amiss a bit here. My bottom line, I want anywhere in the code call `MyClass.DoSomething` while its being static and initialized only once, using settings. However, this alone `Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();` worthy of an answer. This opens paths to solution for my issue. Thank you

Comment: @T.S. while the get works, it should not be abused. It is meant to be used ion startup directly on the `IConfiguration`.

Comment: @T.S. check out the docs here on how to use it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bind-to-an-object-graph

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. And I will try full implementation soon. Also, in the context of my work, there is a better solution for what we do - migrating from framework to core. Apparently Microsoft now has System.configuration nuget package for .net core. This solves a lot of issues with configurations for me. But being naturally curious about all these, I will try and if possible implement these things when they are directly related to web api/mvc projects. however, for all the layers beneath, I am glad there is the aforementioned nuget package

Comment: `Simplifying your design to follow explicit dependency principle should make your code more SOLID and easier to follow and maintain`

I really don't understand in which way it will makes code easier to follow and maintain? :) If we are speaking about regular application code (not libraries, frameworks etc), than all this DI stuff just make code harder to understand and more verbose with almost zero profit. Look on React js - where can it ends when you should pass objects from outside deeply in (they solved that with add global state).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `AppSettings` as parameter from the caller method

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public HomeController(AppSettings settings)
   {
      this.Settings = settings;
   }

   private AppSettings Settings { get; }

   public IActionResult Index()
   {
      MyClass.DosomeThing(this.Settings);
   }
}

internal static MyClass
{
    internal static void DosomeThing(AppSettings settings)
    {
        // acquire my service
        // use it to retrieve some value
        // continue with my logic

    }
}
```

Comment: Not what I am looking for.

Comment: Then, you have (and should) to follow the [Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5233410/nkosi) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56386005/1401886).
That's the correct class design.